# How to overload template operator+ to work with const char* and const char[]?

Tags: c++, c++17, operator-overloading

My question may be open to interpretation cause I`m not sure about a specific error I've encountered.
So I'll appreciate any idea or even solution.

#### Problem :

I'm working on my custom Logger class, based on [this](https://github.com/bschiffthaler/BSlogger) repo.
I've made many changes, including adding `overloaded operator+` to assemble/push incoming `log_txt` into `std::map (K - thread_id, V - string_log)`.

So:

1. `operator()` - add time and status to the std::map;
2. `operator+` - MUST assemble all text and values and push resulting `string` into std::map;
3. `operator<<` - release log at once to avoid text conflicts between logs from other threads.

```
log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " + to_string(1111) + " val\n";
         ///> Will work but than i have to implement all possible types cast...
         ///> I'm trying to keep the code easy to read. 

log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " + 1111 + " val\n";
         ///> Won't work --> error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [6]’ to binary ‘operator+’
         ///> comment: "thread ONE : " + 1111 - const char* and  + "val\n" - const char[6]
```

My `overloaded operator+` as func-member of the Logger class:

```
template <typename T>
Logger& Logger::operator+(const T& s){
    lock_guard<mutex> lock(_mutex);
    if (auto search = _th_streams.find(this_thread::get_id()); search != _th_streams.end()){
            stringstream ss;
            ss << s;
            search->second.append(ss.str());
            return *this;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I'm sure, my `operator+` implementation may be far from ideal but I'm curious is it possible to solve the error by editing **only my** `operator+`?

Overload ooperator+ or to_string()

Comment: Unfortunately operators can only be overloaded for classes. Operators cannot be overload for native types. Pro tip: `log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " << to_string(1111) << " val\n";` -- doesn't that look familiar?

Comment: With [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) `a << b + c` is `a << (b + c)`. So you use built-in `const char*` + `int`.

Comment: typically you'd go for `log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " << 1111 << " val\n";`, which can be done by using your `operator<<` overload only

Comment: what should the outcome of `log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " + to_string(1111) + " val\n";` be ?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - yes, and i initially used it, but i wanted to get more control by dividing add_head/assemble/release operations into 3 dif. operators. As I remember there is logic in it (the sequence of operators is `()`->`+`->`<<`) so I'm just curious.   @463035818_is_not_an_ai - the log is `[time][status]:thread ONE: 1111 val`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Forgot to mention: if I implement 2 actions (`assemble_msg` and `release`) in `operator<<` then its implementation will look ugly. But I got the idea. There is only this option. Thanks! @Ted Lyngmo -  I`ve never used it although I`ve read about it. Will try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of operator precedence, you'll need to adjust *something* in the requirements.

I would go for

```cpp
log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " << 1111 << " val";
```

which is recognizable by most C++ programmers.

I would rewrite the requirements so that

1. `operator()` - Acquires, in a thread-safe manner, a reference to the `std::string` in the `std::map` that is unique for this thread and adds time and status to it.
2. `operator<<` - Appends to the `std::string` above.
3. At the end of the full expression, additional measures should be possible if needed.

The additional measures could be to send the log entry to a central logger. In my example I just add `\n` to mark the end of this logging entry.

- The `std::map` is here only locked while fetching the `std::string` from it. Logging to the individual `std::string`s in the map can then be done without locking.
- `operator()` returns a proxy object (`expr`) that keeps a reference to the `std::string` in the `std::map`
- At the end of the full expression, the proxy object dies and can then perform any additional finalization that is needed.

```cpp
class Logger {
    struct expr {
        ~expr() {
            // the end of the full logging expression
            th_stream += '\n';
        }
        template <class T>
        expr& operator<<(const T& s) {
            std::ostringstream ss;
            ss << s;
            th_stream.append(ss.str());
            return *this;
        }
        
        std::string& th_stream;
    };

public:
    expr operator()(loglevel level) {        
        std::string& th_stream = [&]() -> std::string& {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            return _th_streams[std::this_thread::get_id()];
        }();
        th_stream += std::string("TIMESTAMP ") + std::to_string(level) + ' ';
        return {th_stream};
    }

private:
    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::map<std::thread::id, std::string> _th_streams;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fb6a8Gv6j)

Comment: To be honest, I didn’t understand your concept at first). But the more I dig, the more I agree with your implementation. Just to complete my “self-education”:
So basically you init-t `expr` obj. by returning it from `operator()`?
Is this a standard implementation in regular development, or is it a cool idea that doesn't fit in production? Because I've never seen such an implementation before!

Comment: @Anton-Vas Your understanding is correct. Similar proxy objects are indeed used "in the wild" and exist even in some (most) implementations of the standard library. One that's (in)famous is the one returned by [`std::vector<bool>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference). Perhaps not a good example because people hate that one, but still, it's there :-) In this case `expr` is used to be able to detect the end of the full expression, so it's not exactly the same but these proxy objects are definitely used.

Comment: ... and if you need something more involved at the end of the full expression, you could have `expr` store a reference to the `Logger` and call a non-`static` member function in it. So, with this setup you have a clear start and end of a logging expression while minimizing the time the map is locked. I'm not 100% sure about having any kind of map for this though. In a busy logging environment, the locking and lookups in the map could become a bottleneck. I haven't tried it out, but a `thread_local std::string` _could_ be an alternative.

Comment: Another idea could be to not store `std::string`s but a `struct` with a `time_point` member and in there you could also store a `std::source_location` which requires that you make it `operator()(loglevel, const std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())` and then copy that to the `struct`. `source_location` is only available since C++20, but `g++` has one working in `<experimental/source_location>` that we use at work (and we're also using C++17). [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/53erbMq5E)

Comment: @Anton-Vas I was thinking of a version that only acquires a lock _once_ per thread. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/aEj7ns9KP). It will only put the threads log-entries in the `map` when the thread dies and that's the only time it will lock. I think using a `thread_local` like this instead of locking the map and looking up the thread entry in the map for every logging entry will be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager you need the final `<<` to do something special, and this is why you opted to have both `operator<<` and `operator+`. If this is not the case, this answer is useless, disregard it.

You can go for:

```
log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " << to_string(1111) << " val\n" << Logger::flush;
```

Have `Logger::operator<<` do what your `Logger::operator+`used to do, but define:

```
class Logger
{
    struct flush_t {} flush;
};

Logger& Logger::operator<<(Logger::flush_t);
```

Comment: "flush" has no special meaning. "release" would work too obviously.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible to get this line

```
log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " + 1111 + " val\n";
```

to work by modifying only your `operator+` overload. Even if you accept to modify `operator<<` too, this line cannot do what you intend.

The reason is that `+` has higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `+` and the expression is grouped like this:

```
log(LOG_WARN) << (("thread ONE : " + 1111) + " val\n");
```

You cannot overload `operator+` for `const char[]` and `int`.

There are several ways to go about this. You can introcude special types that come with appropriate `operator+` overload, something along the line of:

```
log(LOG_WARN) << X{"thread ONE : "} + Y{1111} + Z{" val\n"};
```

where `X`,`Y`, and `Z` are that types with `operator+` implemented accordingly.

Alternatively consider to drop `operator+` and use `operator<<` all the way through:

```
log(LOG_WARN) << "thread ONE : " + 1111 + " val\n";
```

If you need the last `<<` to do something special you can either follow what YSC suggested in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76945705/4117728), or make `log(LOG_WARN)` return some light-weight object which does the action in its destructor.